# Animating div with if statement not working

Tags: jquery, if-statement, animation

What I am trying to accomplish is a simple div animation, where the div expands for 200px each time someone clicks on it. I have created a variable sizeCounter, which would grow for 200 each time the div is clicked. When the sizeCounter reaches 700, I want the div to change it's background-color property to green. However, it's not working. What is wrong with my code?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var sizeCounter = 100;

  $(".box").click(function() {
    $(".box").animate({
      height: "+=200px",
      width: "+=200px"
    }, 1000);

    sizeCounter += 200;

    $(".text").animate({
      opacity: "0.5",
      top: "+=60px"
    });
  });

  if (sizeCounter === 700) {
    $(".box").click(function() {
      $(".box").css({
        "background-color": "green"
      });
    });
  }
});
```

```css
.box {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: darkblue;
  position: relative;
}

.text {
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box">
  <p class="text">Click me!</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that your `if` statement only executes once when the page loads and the `div` is only `100px` width.

To fix this you need to check the width within the callback of `animate()` so that it detects the width changing. Try this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var sizeCounter = 100;

  $(".box").click(function() {
    $(".box").animate({
      height: "+=200px",
      width: "+=200px"
    }, 1000, function() {
      sizeCounter += 200;
      if (sizeCounter === 700) {
        $(".box").click(function() {
          $(".box").css({
            "background-color": "green"
          });
        });
      }
    });

    $(".text").animate({
      opacity: "0.5",
      top: "+=60px"
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.box {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: darkblue;
  position: relative;
}

.text {
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box">
  <p class="text">Click me!</p>
</div>
```